# How do I my code from saying things like 'lol' and 'br' are words?

Tags: python

Here is my code (a palindrome checker which also checks if the input is a word or not by comparing it with a text file). I am trying to make it so that the code only says it's a word if it's actually a word because now parts of words like 'pr' and 'la' are counting as words.

```
a = 0
with open('wordlist.txt') as file:
    contents = file.read()


print('Hi. This program will check if the word that you enetered is a palindrome.')
while a==0:
    wordlist = open('wordlist.txt' , 'r+')
    index = 0
    letters = []
    lettersreversed = []
    
    word = input('Enter a word: ')
    wordwithspace = word + '\n'

    for i in range(len(word)):
        letters.append(word[index])
        index = index + 1

    index1 = len(word) -1

    for i in range(len(word)):
        lettersreversed.append(word[index1])
        index1 = index1 - 1

    if letters == lettersreversed and wordwithspace in contents:
        print(word, 'is a palindrome!','\n')
    elif letters == lettersreversed and wordwithspace not in contents:
        print(word, 'is a palindrome however it is not a word.','\n')
    elif letters != lettersreversed and wordwithspace in contents:
        print(word, 'is not a  palindrome however it is a word.','\n')
    else:
        print(word, 'is not a palindrome.', '\n')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: youll need a list of all the words to check each of your words against ...

Comment: Are those words in your wordlist?

Comment: Maybe you want to `split` your `contents` so that it is a list of words instead of one big string.

Answer (score 0):

Your `contents = file.read()` is one big string. So if you check if a string is `in contents` then that will be true for any sequence of characters in the string, even if they are not a whole word.

Alternatively,

```
contents = file.read().split()
```

Now `contents` is a list of words, so `in contents` will only be true for a word in that list.

Even better,

```
contents = set(file.read().split())
```

Now it is a set of words, which is much faster to check containment.

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored some of your code. Your issue was checking if it's `in contents` as it's a huge string. Adding the `\n` doesn't make sure the word doesn't end with the given word (e.g. `toast` and `ast`).

First, load your wordlist as a set:

```
with open('wordlist.txt') as file:
    # Strip all lines off whitespaces, and move them into a set for fast lookup.
    wordlist = frozenset(map(str.strip, file))
```

Then ask for a word:

```
word = input('Enter a word: ')
```

Lastly, check if it's a palindrome:

```
if word == word[::-1] and word in contents:
    print("Palindrome and a real word!")
```

All together:

```
with open('wordlist.txt') as file:
    # Strip all lines off whitespaces, and move them into a set for fast lookup.
    wordlist = frozenset(map(str.strip, file))

while True:
    word = input('Enter a word: ')
    if word == word[::-1]:
        if word in contents:
            print("Palindrome and a real word!")
        else:
            print("Palindrome and a fake word!")
    else:
        if word in contents:
            print("Not a palindrome but a real word!")
        else:
            print("Not a palindrome and not a word!")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_palendromic(string: str) -> bool:
    """
     | The first `if` statement checks if the
     | length of the string is even, if it is
     | then it splits the string in half.
     | If the string is odd then it still splits
     | the string but ignores the middle letter
     | as it is erelivant.
    """
    if len(string) % 2 == 0:
        firstpart, secondpart = string[:len(string)//2], string[len(string)//2:]

    else:
        firstpart  = string[0:len(string)//2]
        secondpart = string[len(string)//2 if len(string)%2 == 0 else ((len(string)//2)+1):]
        # will ignore the middle letter if the string is odd

    return firstpart[::-1] == secondpart
    """
    [:-1]  reverses the string and then compares it to the
           second part of the string, the doble equals sign
           is used to compare the two strings, returning a
           blloean
    """


# example
print(is_palendromic('racecar'))
# will print True

print(is_palendromic('racecar_'))
# will print False
```